# Loading a Mesh in OpenCV Python with viz module

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am creating an AR-app, where you can virtually try on shoes. For now I have the location of the foot calculated using SolvePnp. Now I want to render the 3D object (.obj) file on top of the image, using the OpenCv Viz module. (Manually compiling worked)

I want to load the object as an cv::viz::Mesh object using the cv::viz::Mesh::load function, but I don't find the corresponding Python function call.

I tried

```py
mesh = cv2.viz_Mesh()
mesh.load('shoe.obj', cv2.viz_Mesh_LOAD_OBJ)
```

and also

```py
mesh = cv2.viz_Mesh_load('shoe.obj', cv2.viz_Mesh_LOAD_OBJ)
```

I always get the error:
`AttributeError: 'cv2.viz_Mesh' object has no attribute 'load'`

Using the `dir()` function from python I found all other methods except the load method, which is a static method (that's probably why it isn't here).

```py
>>> dir(cv2) #contains the Viz Classes
['', ... , 'viz',... ,'viz_Mesh] 

>>> dir(cv2.viz) #Stuff like Enums , Colors etc
['',...'Color_amethyst', ..., 'MOUSE_EVENT_MOUSE_DBL_CLICK'...]

>>> dir(cv2.viz_Mesh) #pyhton functions and other non static methods
['__class__', ... , 'colors','polygons']
```

Does someone know what the correct python call is?

Appendix: the cv2.viz_Mesh_LOAD_OBJ and cv2.viz_MESH_LOAD_OBJ represent only integers 2 ( = enums), thus

```py
>>>print(cv2.viz_MESH_LOAD_OBJ)
>>>print(cv2.viz_Mesh_LOAD_OBJ)
2
2
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I overlooked some methods in the `dir(cv2.viz)`.
The correct python call would be

```py
mesh = cv2.viz.readMesh('./shoe.ply')
```

It only accepts the path to .ply file, but not to .obj files (Version 4.5.5). Maybe other formats will be added in newer versions